# name 'Yes' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, logic

When I get further in the code it tells me ''Yes'' is not defined.The code is asking the user how long they worked and calculating the code.

I've tried a few minor changes to that statement. It gave me the same results.

When the user answers with an ''Yes'' ; I want the code to calculate the gross pay

```
Overtimeflag = 50

if Overtimeflag == 50: 

 Overtimeflag = True

Else:

Overtimeflag = False


Name = input('Whats your first and last name')

Address = input('Whats your address')

HoursWorked=float(input('How many years have you been working here'))

Overtime=float(input('how long did you work today'))

if HoursWorked > 40:

   print('You are qualified for overtime pay')

elif Overtime >= 2:

    Overtime = HoursWorked - 40

else:

    print('In order to earn overtime, the user must have worked for at least 2 years')

grossPay =float(input('Whats your hourly rate'))

Overtimeflag =input('Did you work 50 hours this week')

##Calculate the gross pay with the following formula

if grossPay == Yes:

    Overtime2 * grossPay * 2 + HoursWorked - Overtimeflag * grossPay

else:

    print('You do not earn overtime due to lack of years of service')
```

Comment: It would help if you posted your actual code... We aren't magicians.

Comment: There are other problems with your code. You are comparing `grossPay` to `Yes` but `grossPay` is a float (`float(input('Whats your hourly rate'))`). And what is `Overtime2`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes has to be a string as it is not defined earlier.

```
Overtimeflag = 50

if Overtimeflag == 50: 
 Overtimeflag = True
else:
    Overtimeflag = False


Name = input('Whats your first and last name')

Address = input('Whats your address')

HoursWorked=float(input('How many years have you been working here'))

Overtime=float(input('how long did you work today'))

if HoursWorked > 40:
   print('You are qualified for overtime pay')
elif Overtime >= 2:
    Overtime = HoursWorked - 40
else:
    print('In order to earn overtime, the user must have worked for at least 2 years')
grossPay =float(input('Whats your hourly rate'))
Overtimeflag3 =input('Did you work 50 hours this week')
##Calculate the gross pay with the following formula

if Overtimeflag3 == "Yes":
    Overtime2 = grossPay * 2 + HoursWorked - Overtimeflag * grossPay
    print("Overtime pay: ",Overtime2 )
else:
    print('You do not earn overtime due to lack of years of service')
```

OUTPUT:

```
Whats your first and last namecd scsd
Whats your addresscsd
How many years have you been working here9
how long did you work today99
Whats your hourly rate9
Did you work 50 hours this weekYes
Overtime pay:  18.0
```